# Cumulocity - Custom widget configuration

Tags: cumulocity

I'm writing a chart widget in cumulocity platform.
In widget comes with the platform, 
I can select data point after I select device:
[image]

But the widget I wrote can only select device, there is no data point option for me to select:
[image]

I know there is [`c8yComponentsProvider`](http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/api/c8y.ui.provider:c8yComponentsProvider) that has options for me to select if I want device target or not. Is there a way for me to choose what data point I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the device selector in the options of the `c8yComponentsProvider`:

```
options: {
  noDeviceTarget: true
}
```

And then use the following directive in your widget config html:

```
<c8y-data-point-list datapoints="data.datapoints"></c8y-data-point-list>
```

You need to set the data points to choose in the `data.datapoints` object on the widget configuration controller. Therefore you can search for managed objects with the fragment `c8y_DataPoint`.

In the document is an example how to do that with the [c8yInventory](http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/api/c8y.core.service:c8yInventory) service:

```
var filters = {fragmentType: 'c8y_DataPoint', withParents: true};
$scope.data = {};
c8yInventory.list(filters).then(function (devices) {
  $scope.data.datapoints = [];
  _.forEach(devices, function(dp) {
    $scope.data.datapoints.push(dp);
  });
});
```

Note that the `c8y-data-point-list` is a nonofficial directive. If you face any problems or you want a specific look, you might be faster by writing your own directive.

Comment: I can show the data point option in my browser now.
But is there a way to get what datapoint the user select?
With `c8yInventory.list` i can get all the datapoint, but i still don't know what data the user select.

Comment: If you use the `c8y-data-point-list` a property called __active should be set on each datapoint which the user activates.

Comment: i didn't see any __active property on the selected datapoint. is there a function i have to call to get this property?

Comment: I checked it twice and if you use `c8y-data-point-list` the directive adds a `__active` flag to show that it is used. Can you pls verify by adding a watcher on `scope.data.datapoints` and toggle the datapoints in/out? Otherwise pls open a new question with details and link it here.

Comment: @WahahaXDDI am facing the same issue I am unable to find which all data points that are selected. Where you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @WahahaXDDI how to access the save button in my controller? Could you please help.

Answer (score 2):

From angular 2 it has to be done in this way.

In my custom widget project I added to the usedValue secion of `app.module.ts` as follows.

```js
useValue: {
    id: 'acme.text.widget', // 3.
    label: 'Text widget',
    description: 'Can display a text',
    component: WidgetDemo, // 4.
    configComponent: WidgetConfigDemo,
    data: {
        ng1: {
            options: {
                noDeviceTarget: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```